# Graph editor for shape key animation

Tags: animation, shape-keys, graph-editor

I have animation where object changes his shape using shape keys, and I want to make some animation smoothing with graph editor. Is there a way to use graph editor for shape key animation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By keyframing the influence value of the *Shape Key* <kbd>I</kbd> (while mouse over the slider, <kbd>RMB</kbd> to open the context menu) you can edit a the [F-Curve](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/Graph/FCurves) in the [*Graph Editor*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/Graph).

[image]

Comment: If it is an Absolute shape key instead of Relative, you'll be keyframing the Evaluation Time.